# many to many relation returns null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a many to many relation between the tables `user` and `clinic` and the third table is `user_clinics`. All three tables returns their values perfectly individually, but when i call `App\User::find(1)->clinics` or its inverse it returns `null`. Moreover, `user_clinic` has `user_id` and `clinic_id` and also `previlage_id` as a foreign key.

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_clinics','user_id','clinic_id');
}

public function clinics() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class,'user_clinics','clinic_id','user_id');
}

public function adminDashboard(Request $request) {
    $clinic = new Clinic();
    $User_clinic = new User_clinic();
    $user = new User();

    $clinic->name = $request->name;
    $clinic->address = $request->address;

    if($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $fileName = $request->logo->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->logo->storeAs('public/logos',$fileName);
        $clinic->logo = $request->logo;
    }

    $clinic->save();

    $User_clinic->user_id = auth::user()->id;
    $test=$User_clinic->clinic_id = $clinic->id;

    //now hardcoded previlage_id but deal with it in future...
    $User_clinic->previlage_id = 1;
    $User_clinic->save();

    $test= $clinic::find(2)->users;

    dd($test);

     //return view("admin.dashboard.dashboardFirstPage");
}
```

Comment: i have a table in database user_clinics and create its model user_clinic for make its relation to another table that is previlage. is it ok or have any issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your relationship is not quiet right:

```
public function users() {
 return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_clinics','user_id','clinic_id');
}

public function clinics() {
 return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class,'user_clinics','clinic_id','user_id');
}
```

It should be like below:

In User model:

```
public function clinics() {
 return $this->belongsToMany(Clinic::class,'user_clinics','user_id','clinic_id');
}
```

In Clinic model:

```
public function users() {
 return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_clinics','clinic_id','user_id');
}
```

Comment: i will go for it and then reply you.. ;)

Comment: Welcome Adil Happy to help

Comment: is any issue to include a primary key in user_clinics table?

Comment: My pleasure sir.

Comment: no issue occurs if we include a primary key in user_clinics table